# Crashing due to privacy vilation

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, info.plist

This is my info plist I have added all the attributes but still getting privacy violation error.

plist:
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lmv1O.png

error image:
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/gpJ8F.jpg

Comment: share the crash log.

Comment: Please use CMD+SHFT+4 (⌘+⇧+4) to take screen shots instead of taking pictures of your screen.

Comment: @clawesome thanks for the info its very helpful but I dont think thats the answer to my question :)

Comment: As for the privacy violation, what are you trying to do in the app?  There are a number of different privacy permissions that must be specified before using such as user location, address book, user photos, etc.  There's really no way to help you outside guessing with your current issue with how little information given so far.  edit - reference this page to get an idea of what entails a good question on SO: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: We have no clue what your app does. There are a bunch of permissions that exist, we can guess all day what they are but you, as the author, should know what your app does.

Comment: @xTwisteDx I am not the author thats y I have no clue about the permissions it require, I think u cant know what privacy features are added in project unless  go through every code file

Answer (score 1):

Thanks all.
I solved it by generating crash log window->Devices->Select device->View log.
The issue was bluetooth permission was not added in info plist